# Android studio use gradle2.5 dependencies com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.1

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Android studio use gradle2.5 dependencies  com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.1

when i create AndroidLibrary ,   how to create build.gradle?
(I know `apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'` when add a Phone Module  )

Comment: Android studio version 1.4

Answer (score 0):

if your app could use [the latest gradle-experimental](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/), possibly:

- Build native shared libs with: apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'.  one example is in [hello-libs](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs)
- Build native static libs, indirectly supported. It is in [Teapot example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/Teapot). the native-app-glue is built as a static lib and consumed by Teapot application. When you build teapot APK, a static lib of native-activity will be generated forcefully in build directory. Grep it, you will find it. That static lib could be distributed to others

hope this helps. If you could use android studio cmake support, it is simpler[my personal view], the similar examples are in [master-cmake branch](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master-cmake)